# How to Create an Array within an Object Constructor in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to be able to make a list of all instances of a Constructor, so I can check if all of these fit criteria in an IF statement
For Example:

```js
function People() {
  People.allInstances = [];
  People.allInstances.push(this);
}

var Carry = new People();
var Gary = new People();
var Parry = new People();
console.log(People.allInstances);
```

However, I seem to lose all data except for the last instance I created. How can I make that list/array, and then use that array to test if any of them has a certain property?

Comment: I think its because every time you initialize `People` you are resetting `allInstances` into an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor runs every time an instance is constructed with it, but you only want to create an empty array once:

```
function People() {
    People.allInstances.push(this);
}

People.allInstances = [];
```